# Как сделать чтение строки , присваивание его к переменной и нахождение случайного между двумя переменными?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qt-designer

Приложение,которое будет читать строки (LineEdit и LineEdit_2) . Из диапазона двух значений будет выбирать случайное число и вставлять его в (LineEdit_3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 from PySide2 import QtWidgets
    import sys
    from ui import Ui_Form
    import random


# Create App



# Create form and init UI
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

# Hook logic
def bp():
    frst = ui.lineEdit.text()
    twth = ui.lineEdit.text()
    #print("твое случайное число : ")
    rannum = print(random.randint(frst , twth))
    ui.lineEdit_3.setText(str(rannum))

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)
#Run main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ошибка следующая

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in bp
    rannum = print(random.randint(frst , twth))
  File "C:\Users\pavlv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста модуль `ui.py`. И лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: `rannum = print(random.randint(int(frst) , int(twth)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы передаете функции `randint` строки, а нужно числа.
2. Вы присваиваете `rannum` результат, которой отдаст функция `print`, а
   она ничего не отдает.

`rannum = random.randint(int(frst) , int(twth))`